# Spelling: Id vs. ID

Tags: wording

I have several kinds of identifiers in my Windows desktop application. A batch identifier, a job identifier and so on. Each identifier is a unique positive integer, the value has no meaning but to identify a batch, a job, etc. These identifier are displayed in a table. The question now is how to name the columns? In order to get narrow columns I need to shorten "Batch Identifier".

As a non-native english speaker I searched the WEB and I don't get a clear Picture whether "Batch Id" oder "Batch ID" is the right way. Or is there even no right way and both versions are ok?

Comment: `Id` looks a lot like `ld`, in fonts where capital "i" is very similar to "l" can be confusing. Also, I either see "id" or "ID". Can't remember when I've last seen "Id".

Comment: Or jus use Batch - especially if the column names are known to be shortened

Comment: Poke [english.se]

Answer (score 16):

"ID" means "identification." Use that.

"Id" means [something different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#Id) from ID. (Hint: it's Freudian.)

Answer (score 6):

Camel case does not apply to this because Camel case is a style method for programming. You are asking about how to abbreviate an English term. The proper use is ID; never Id.

Unfortunately, this question should be asked on another stackexchange involving such topics where the fuller explanation will be made evident.

Answer (score 4):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151338/id-or-id-on-user-interface, specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151345/881441:

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/ID[2]), the abbreviation is "ID". If it were a correct abbreviation, it would have to be "Id." with the period.

Answer (score 3):

When you have two letters, both should be upper case. When you have three, only the first one should be upper case.

This means that **BatchID** is correct and <strike>**BatchId**</strike> is incorrect.

Reference:[Camel Casing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)

Comment: Thx. I notice that you leave out the blank between Batch and ID. So, **BatchID**, **JobID** is better than **Batch ID**, **Job ID**?

Comment: @gomi42 Yes, as a variable in programming. But in plain language use the space. :-)

Comment: Those rules apply to acronyms, but id is an abbreviation for identifier, not an acronym.

Comment: @BenVoigt The problem of English is that you distinguish these two :p In Czech, we do not make this distinction, and we're happily living.

Comment: @tohecz last I checked identity is an English word. Is it also Czech?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I meant the distinction between acronyms and abbreviations. We don't have that, we call them by the same word. And whatever rules apply to acronyms, they apply to abbreviations as well ;)

Comment: Um, because the question doesn't ask anything about camel case or programming variables, I think this answer is misleading. "ID" as a word is correct not because it has only two letters, it's correct because that's the accepted short form of "identification."

Comment: There are different naming conventions, and they prefer different choices. So you can't declare on of them as universally *incorrect*. Either choice can be correct, as long as it conforms to the convention you chose. I for one avoid `ID` (or `XML`), since it doesn't allow reliable splitting of an identifier into its constituent parts. `getElementById` is an example in a popular language (though it doesn't apply the rule consistently, e.g. it uses `XML` not `Xml`.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151338/id-or-id-on-user-interface)

To summarize though:

**BatchID**, and **JobID**, might look nice, but if you're using `Camel Casing` you're just as likely to run into something like:

**IDAnalytics** and **IDValidation** etc...

Which is (subjectively) confusing

Answer (score -1):

It should be Id and Ok, but DB and IO according to the Microsoft naming convention:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: That link suggests otherwise. *"In Pascal-cased identifiers they should appear as `Id`, and `Ok`*". '**Identifier**' isn't ever going to be in Pascal-case because it is a single word.

Comment: They make a difference in abbreviations vs acronyms.

Comment: They make a difference in abbreviations vs acronyms. It states that ID is an abbreviation and not an acronym, hence the acronym rules do not apply. It also states that *The identifier casing rules take precedence over acronym casing rules.*. Further more it is specified that in a Pascal-case word it should be Id. My interpretation is that it should be Id. Others in my company agree with me. Keep in mind that this is just the microsoft naming convetion.

Comment: "The two abbreviations that can be used in identifiers are ID and OK" - Your link